# php, mysql, html

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to import my all date in sql table into html table please help how can i do this, currently I am having this code

but this is showing all data in one place
i want to show exact what it is in sql table and to html table or anything like that. Thanks

```
 <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("db error");
mysql_select_db("users") or die("db select error");
$query = "SELECT * FROM result";
$result = mysql_query("$query");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)){
    echo"<tr><td>".$row['student_id'];
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Please avoid using the _deprecated_ mysql functions and move to either `mysqli` or `PDO`

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
$result = mysql_query("$query");
```

to this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

And to fetch as much data as needed:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)){
    echo"<tr>" . $row['student_id'] . "</tr>";
    echo"<tr>" . $row['student_name'] . "</tr>";
    echo"<tr>" . $row['student_class'] . "</tr>";
}
```

> Note: I have used the dummy column names, replace `student_name`,
>   `student_class` with the columns you have in your table

**EDIT:**

As expected, Once you have got these issues resolved. Move to `mysqli` and start off with something like:

connection.php:

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "your_db_name_here");

    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect" . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    ?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php   
// if (isset($_POST['your_submit_button_name_here'])) {
include('connection.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM result";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if($result){
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)){
    echo"<tr>" . $row['student_id'] . "</tr>";
    echo"<tr>" . $row['student_name'] . "</tr>";
    echo"<tr>" . $row['student_class'] . "</tr>";
}}
else
echo"Query Failed."; 
// }
?>
```

For more deeper study:

[PHP Manual: MySQL Improved Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

[PHP Manual: PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Your table HTML is invalid :)

Comment: @andrewsi Shhhh fixing ittt

Comment: You should not provide him with a reply that uses deprecated functions. Make him aware that he should rather use mysqli functions or PDO class' methods.

Comment: @CDF this is for you `;-)`